# What is a good way to update a user on login using the MVC design pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I have the following use case:

> Users will be using this website alongside another web service. When they log on to this web service (Service A), Service A should use the API of the other service (Service B) to update the relevant user information.

Given this situation, how do you think I should go about it in terms of MVC. The only code point the user goes through while logging in is through the `create` action of the `SessionsController`. The way I see it, I have a few options, but none of them feel like a clean fit for rails and MVC. First, I could have the `create` action simply make the API calls. Secondly, I could have a separate action that is called to perform the tasks. Thirdly, I could add a class method to the `User` model that performs the update. Does anyone have any experience in handling this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an after_update hook on User to create a background task that would handle the update. Being that you are dealing with a separate service, the task of updating should be offloaded to a background job, such as Resque.